# File not found in C# (when it is there)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

The project file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l12v5vx21lls3p0/RaphaelsLab.zip?dl=0

Screenshot 2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/im0hgczyy95qvzz/Screenshot%202015-01-04%2008.35.16.png?dl=0

I have some high quality weirdness going on here, which part of me wants to think is somehow a permissions problem, and another wants to think is a banjaxx'ed VS install. I have a text file (regular old text file) in the Debug/bin directory which the program doesn't believe exists. Could someone take a look at the Button code under Graviton Reactor, and tell me if there is some magic I'm missing?

Comment: Screenshot 1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/csde7z7rmxk4pzy/Screenshot%202015-01-04%2008.34.42.png?dl=0

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]  Please dont ask us to go elsewhere to see the code you want help with.  it makes the question useless for future readers when the link goes dead.

Comment: And you need to reduce the code down to a minimum if possible, while still reproducing the same problem.

Comment: @user3799003 Did you mark the file as a resource?

Comment: Did you change the default folder location to bin\Debug? I mean I thought the default folder was the one containing the solution file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the file `gravitonreactor.txt` in your project. Your text file is called `gravitonreactor.txt.txt`.

Comment: Bows head lowly. Several years of developing, and I've been hoisted by my own petard (a temporary install of Windows 7). Thank You, Good Sir.

Comment: Complacency of using Windows with the file extensions enabled, then using a temporary install (while awaiting some new hardware / software), I never hit the checkbox to see the file extensions in this install. Happens to be right in my blind spot (especially coming off of a Mint install). PetSerAl is very correct.